# Converting check List in VB.NET to integer

Tags: vb.net

This is my first time working with VB.Net It's a college assignment and is already due for submission.I want to create a simple program that determines if a user has Ebola or not. So, there is a list of checkbox containing the core symptoms of Ebola. If the user selects 4 or more there should be a prompt message saying the user most likely has Ebola otherwise user does not have Ebola.

I have created the form and it works but don't know how to implement the checkbox into numbers that will be summed up.

Here is the code for the form

```
Public Class Checkbxvb  
    Private Sub Checkbxvb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
        Label1.Text = "Click to select the symptoms you are having"  
        CheckBox1.Text = "Fever"  
        CheckBox2.Text = "Loss of appetite"  
        CheckBox3.Text = "sore throat"  
        CheckBox4.Text = "Gastrointestinal Symptoms"  
        CheckBox5.Text = "Unexplained bleeding or bruising"  
        CheckBox6.Text = "Loss of weight"  
        Button1.Text = "Submit"  
        Button2.Text = "Close"  
    End Sub
```

I want to create a button that will collect the user input like I said earlier on. Thanks

Comment: You could check `if checkbox1.checked AndAlso Checkbox4.checked then` for example. Note that this isnt a checkbox list if I look at the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a CheckListBox you can used its CheckedItems collection Count property to get what you need.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You may have Ebola.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You probably don't have Ebola.")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you are using CheckBox controls add them to a List(Of T). The T stands for Type. Create a variable for the list at Form level so it can be seen from the Form.Load and the button click. Then you can loop through your collection and increment a counter when the Checked property is True.

```
Private CkBxList As New List(Of CheckBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CkBxList.AddRange({CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4})
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim counter As Integer
    For Each cb In CkBxList
        If cb.Checked Then
            counter += 1
        End If
    Next
    If counter > 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You may have Ebola.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You probably don't have Ebola.")
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see the code is much simpler with a CheckedListBox. Try to use the control that best suits your purpose.

Comment: Why a collection rather than an array? The point of a collection is that it can grow and shrink dynamically, but there's not use for that in cases like this so an array is more appropriate. The funny thing is that you're actually creating an array anyway, but then passing that to `AddRange` rather than just assigning it to a field.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Got it. I guess collections add an extra layer on top of array so array is less expensive. Yes?

Comment: Correct. A List(Of T) stores is items in an array anyway. It doubles the size of that array each time an item is added that it has no room for but, if there's no adding or removing, the extra layer of complexity adds no value. Some people use collections all the time but you should still use arrays when they provide all you need. One point to note is that arrays provide direct access to element values for value types, while a collection returns a copy when you get an item.